# Системная команда в терминал Linux на python

Tags: python, linux, linux-mint

Интересен момент передачи системных команд на Python в Linux.
Например такой код работает.

```
import os
command = "python --version"
res = os.system(command)
print("Returned Value: ", res)
```

А такой нет. Выдает: sh: строка 1: amixer: команда не найдена

```
import os
command = "amixer -c 2 set 'Output Select' 'Headphone'"
res = os.system(command)
print("Returned Value: ", res)
```

Интересно почему. Спасибо.

Comment: ну наверное потому что нет такой команды

Comment: `which amixer` тоже самое выдает?

Comment: @DiD нет, в данном случае пишет which: invalid option -- 'c'
which: no amixer in (/home/dmitry/PycharmProjects/swap/venv/bin ....и так далее

Comment: добавьте исполняемый файл `amixer` в любую папку из перечисленных через двоеточие в переменной `$PATH`. такая папка может быть `/usr/bin` лмбо просто `/bin`.

Comment: @alex есть. в терминале работает. Переключает источник звука

Comment: ну вот сделайте в терминале which amixer, а не в пайтоне. вам покажет тогда путь расположения исполняемого файла. это будет то что вам нужно

Comment: укажите вместо `amixer`  полный путь `/usr/bin/amixer` и все заработает.

Comment: правда, менять звук все равно не будет, так как окружение запуска питона у вас почему-то полностью эмулируется. вероятно, будет выдавать другую ошибку, что-то вроде недоступности сервера ALSA....

Comment: Увы, не помогает. Даже от виртуального окружения избавился.

Comment: выполните `/usr/bin/env` в эмуляторе терминала и в функции `os.system()`, и сравните вывод.

Comment: А зачем вы такое делаете?

Comment: @0andriy хочу делаю програмку чтобы быстро переключать выходы. Видать такое в консоль передать нельзя, как команду.

Comment: Ну используйте _python-alsa_ пакет с биндингами. `os.system()` — это в принципе неправильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче, похоже проблема была с правами. Если обращаться к amixer из /usr/bin/amixer, где он и находился, то по какой-то причине ничего не происходит.
А если скопировать amixer в папку с проектом, и вызывать оттуда, пример ниже, то все отлично работает. Плюс нужно юзать subprocess. Мб кому поможет.

```
import subprocess
        def Headphones(self):
            subprocess.Popen ("/home/dmitry/PycharmProjects/2/amixer -c 2 set 'Output Select' 'Headphone'", shell=True)
```